# UK visa refusal under Appendix V Section 3.6

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

Because my company didn't verify information in a call they received, it resulted in my visa being refused. It was a mistake made by the company employee. He was new and couldn't respond properly to the Embassy.

Should I reapply and include a letter from the company chairman explaining the massive mistake?

Comment: Can you post your refusal letter (with your personal information blacked out)?

Comment: You should not reapply without guidance from a UK immigration lawyer. This is also something your company should pay for, but that's another discussion...

Comment: How I should add the refusal letter please suggest